Definition of Recurrence vs Absorption
Suppose I have these two Discrete Time Markov Chains (DTMC):

Transition Matrix for a 3-State Markov Chain with an Absorbing State:

$$
M_1 = P_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where:

$p_{ij}$ is the probability of transitioning from state i to state j.

$\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_{ij} = 1
$



Transition Matrix for a 3-State Markov Chain without an Absorbing State:

$$ M_2 = P_{ij} =
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} \\
p_{31} & p_{32} & p_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, consider the following theorem about Discrete Time Markov Chains (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eharchol/Probability/chapters/chpt25.pdf#page=12):
Theorem 25.12: For an irreducible, aperiodic finite-state Markov chain with transition matrix P, we have:
$$
\pi_j = \frac{1}{m_{jj}} > 0
$$
where

$m_{jj}$ is the mean time between visits to state $j$ (i.e. mean recurrence time) and $\pi_j = \lim_{n \to \infty} (P^n)_{ij}$.
$\pi_j$ represents the steady-state probability of being in state $j$.
$m_{jj}$ is the mean recurrence time, or the expected time for the chain to return to state $j$ given that it is currently in state $j$.
$(P^n)_{ij}$ is the $(i, j)$-th entry of the $n$-th power of the transition matrix $P$, which gives the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ in $n$ steps.

My Question: Can Theorem 25.12 be applied in both Markov Chains, i.e. can recurrence be treated as a special case of absorption?
For example:

$M_1$: What is the expected number of steps needed to go from State 1 to State 3 (absorption)?

$M_1$: What is the expected number of steps needed to go from State 1 to State 1 (recurrence in an absorbing chain)?

$M_2$: What is the expected number of Steps needed to go from State 1 to State 3?

$M_2$: What is the expected number of Steps needed to go from State 1 to State 1 (recurrence in a non-absorbing chain)?


Or does this theorem only apply to a specific situation in only non-absorbing Markov Chains?
Also, does anyone know if it is possible to determine the probability distribution of $m_{jj}$ in a DTMC?
Thanks!
References:

Proving The Fundamental Theorem of Markov Chains



Can Theorem 25.12 be applied in both Markov Chains, i.e. can recurrence be treated as a special case of absorption?

The answer is, in general, no. To apply the theorem 25.12, we need the Markov chain to be: (a) irreducible : every states need to be communicate to other states, and (b) aperiodic: every states have period of $1$.
1. The transition matrix has absorbing state The chain cannot be irreducible, as if the chain starts at the absorbing state, the chain cannot escape that state.
2. The transition matrix has no absorbing state Without any further assumption, we can choose the transition matrix to be "periodic". Say:
$$
     \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & 0 & 1\\
          1 & 0 & 0\\
          0 & 1 & 0
     \end{pmatrix}
$$
then every states of this Markov chain have period of $3$. Similarly, we can choose a transition matrix so that the Markov chain to be "non-irreducible":
$$
     \begin{pmatrix}
          1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
          0  & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
          0 & 1/2 & 1/2
     \end{pmatrix}
$$
This Markov chain is not irreducible, as the second state is accessible from the first state, but the first state is not accessible from the second state.
Again, these notions of irreducible and aperiodic have been explained in the link you post, just a few pages above: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eharchol/Probability/chapters/chpt25.pdf#page=12
